# can i get drawable from byte array?

Tags: sqlite, blob

**this is how i success to get the native Icon of an application and first display it and eventually send it into a database as a Blob:**

```
Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("application_name");
            builder.setMessage("Vous avez cliqué sur : " + resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
            Drawable iconApp;
            iconApp=resolveInfo.activityInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());

            BitmapDrawable bmd = (BitmapDrawable) iconApp;
            Bitmap bm = bmd.getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
            SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter =new SQLiteAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());
            mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
            String s=resolveInfo.activityInfo.name;
            mySQLiteAdapter.insertphoto(bitmapdata);
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert(s);
```

**and i am trying to get it back:
    **like that:

```
SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter =new SQLiteAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                     mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
                     byte[] buffer = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAllphoto();
                     mySQLiteAdapter.close();

                     Drawable image = null;
                     image =  new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.length));
                     Bitmap b= convertByteArrayToBitmap(buffer);

                     //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(content,0,content.length);

                     //image =  new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(content, 0, content.length));
                     Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
                     builder.setTitle("blob");
                     builder.setIcon(image);
                     builder.show();
```

and eventually here my mmethode queuAllphoto part ofthe class SQliteAdapter:

```
public byte[] queueAllphoto(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_CONTENT_photo};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE_photo, columns, 
                null, null, null, null, null);
        byte[] result = null; 

        int index_CONTENT = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT_photo);
        for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !(cursor.isAfterLast()); cursor.moveToNext()){
            result = cursor.getBlob(index_CONTENT) ;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

that methode returns a byte array it' s that byte array i would like to work on by displaying each blob in AlerDialogue for exemple!i am struggling to convert this byte array in a drawable because i am thinking to use it in a Builder(AlertDialogue) with the methode SetIcon(Drawable)

Comment: is my question too much basic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by changing the type of return (Bitmap instead of byte array) and adding bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result, 0, result.length) i can now use the bitmap
to change par exemple an imageview like this:

```
 Bitmap bm = null;
                 SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter =new SQLiteAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                 mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
                 bm=mySQLiteAdapter.queueAllphoto();
                 mySQLiteAdapter.close();
                 imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

and there you got the method queueAllphoto():

public Bitmap queueAllphoto(){

```
     Bitmap bitmap;

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_CONTENT_photo};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE_photo, columns, 
            null, null, null, null, null);
    byte[] result = null; 

    int index_CONTENT = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT_photo);
    for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !(cursor.isAfterLast()); cursor.moveToNext()){
        result = cursor.getBlob(index_CONTENT) ;


    }

    bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result, 0, result.length);
    return bitmap;
}
```